# copy angular scope variable that is bidirectionally derived from parent without having the copy also be bidirectional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Supppose I have this:

```
<div class="dostuff" some-obj="parentScopeObj">

sAngular.app.directive('dostuff', ['$compile', function($compile){
  return   {
    restrict : 'C',
    scope: { someObj : '=' },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs){  
      element.click(function(){
        scope.parentScopeObj = scope.someObj;
        scope.parentScopeObj.first = 'some modification';
        scope.$apply();
     });
    }
```

Basically the goal is to have a new, isolated scope.parentScopeObj in which if you modify stuff in the directive's scope.parentScopeObj and perform $apply(), the modification will not  propagate to the parent scope's parentScopeObj variable.

I tried.

1. Just a simple scope.parentScopeObj = scope.someObj; as in the above however, modifying the directive's scope.parentScopeObj will still propagate to the parent scope's parentScopeObj accordingly
2. scope.parentScopeObj = angular.copy(scope.someObj); however this caused my browser to crash in the actual scenario I'm using so this is a no go
3. scope.parentScopeObj = $.extend(true, {}, scope.someObj); however, modifying the directive's scope.parentScopeObj will still propagate to the parent scope's parentScopeObj accordingly

so how can I go about doing a deep copy of the scope.someObj variable (which is bidirectional to the parent) without also having the deep copy bidirectional with the parent? angular.copy was a no go as it crashed the browser consistently

Comment: @Mark Rajcok, I summon thee

Comment: Odd, I didn't get notified of your comment... maybe I have to post a comment first...  Too bad angular.copy() didn't work.  I'm glad to hear that jQuery's extend() worked (at least it did some kind of copy without crashing).  I don't understand why a deep copy via extend() didn't work.  Can you create a minimal example of the failure?